# Outlook 2013 is not able to send/receive email when connected to Citrix RDP Session

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, citrix-receiver

I have 2 laptops; Windows 7 and Windows 8.1. Both has Office 2013 installed. Both have my TPIA email account configured and works just fine. I can send emails, receive them.

The thing is, when I connect to my organisation and launch my remote desktop from Citrix XenApp, I cannot get any emails. When I hit send/receive, I get the error 0x8004102A/B. The only way to have Outlook 2013 to work fine again is to reboot.

Any idea on this one?

Comment: Are you connecting via VPN or what do you mean by that?

Comment: No, no VPN. There is no extrs IP layers on my IP address.